# Script to change cookie expiration to 6 months

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm definitely new to Javascript, but I need to implement a tag within GTM to update 2 cookie values to 6 months for any unique user after the are loaded on the page.

I have the following script to alter the expiration date:

```
<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2)
    return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}


var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime()+(365*24*60*60*1000));
var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
console.log("expires: " + expires);
var cookieName = "CookieA";
var OABCcookieName = "CookieB";

function updateCookieExpiration() {
    var cookie = getCookie(cookieName);
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookie + expires + ";path=/; Samesite=Lax;" //domain=" + domain + ";";

    var OABCcookie = getCookie(OABCcookieName);
    document.cookie = OABCcookieName + "=" + OABCcookie + expires + ";path=/; Samesite=Lax;" //domain=" + domain + ";";
}

</script>
```

My question is, if I add the following script, update 365 to 180, and call the updateCookieExpiration() function - won't the function be called on every page and cause the cookie expiration to always reset to 6 months?

If so, is there additional logic that I need to add to make sure the cookie expiration hasn't already been reset for a unique visitor, to avoid the scenario described?

Any help troubleshooting would be great and very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition check if the Cookie name already exist:

```js
// You may prefer using max-age here
const sixMonthMaxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 180;
var newCookieName = "CookieA";

function updateCookieExpiration() {
    const cookie = getCookie(cookieName);
    // If cookie doesn't exist
    if(!cookie) {
      document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookie + ";"  + "max-age=" sixMonthMaxAge + ";"
    }
}
```

**Using [js-cookie library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)**

Using library that abstract Cookie management can be a good idea, even more if you have to manager multiple cookies.

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const sixMonthMaxAge = 180; // You can provide the max-age in days
var newCookieName = "CookieA";

function updateCookieExpiration() {
    const cookie = Cookies.get(cookieName);
    if(!cookie) {
      Cookie.set(cookieName, 'your_value', { expires: sixMonthMaxAge })
    }
}

Cookies.set('foo', 'bar')
```